# Monitor MySQL Slave replication status

Tags: mysql, database-replication

After committing a SQL insert operation in a MySQL master, we can't find that result in the slave for at least 5 seconds. This situation doesn't happen in every query, but it does happen occasionally.

Does anybody know how we can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to check slave status or check this link [**Replication Status**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-administration-status.html)

```
Show slave status;
```

Comment: Hi, I have check it, it's always 0 seconds behind master. It makes me feel wired

Comment: yes, it's working. But in my python code, after I insert something in master, I can not find it in slave in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `show slave status;` query and check the output and still if `seconds_behind_master` shows `0` and new updates does not apply on slave then then reset your master settings by using [Chnage Master.. command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/change-master-to.html)